# Linear decomposition of a function

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Given a function $f$, with inputs $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ determine a function $g$ such that $f(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(x_i)$. More specifically for the special case of $f(x)=e^{x}$. This function $g$ need not be exact but resulting in a good approximation would suffice, this is required for exponentiation when each party holds additive shares. The current naive approximation in use is $g(x)=e^{x}$ but shows very high error rates. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just expand in a Taylor series? That is,
\begin{align}
f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) &= \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_i + x_i^2 + \dots)\\
&\approx \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_i)\\
&\approx 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n} + x_i \right)
\end{align}
So that you can take $g(x) = \frac{1}{n} + x_i$. This approximation is only good when all $|x_i| \ll 1$ so it may or may not be useful for whatever you're trying to apply this towards.

Comment: I think that doesn't work because the data range can go from 0-2^32-1, with floats possible

Comment: Then I'm not so sure the form you're looking for is feasible. If you have 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} \Rightarrow g'(x_j) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} \Rightarrow g^{(k)}(x_j) = g'(x_j)$$
That is, all derivatives of this function are equal to each other. The only function that satisfies this, as you've already tried, is $g(x_j) = e^{x_j}$. Perhaps someone else might have better ideas though..

Comment: Yes, but in addition I do not need an exact answer an iterative method would work just as fine. The goal was to approximate $e^x$ rather than decompose it exactly